# Extract between parenthesis list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, string, list

I have a big list from a txt file that I want to extract, I have been looking this for days and no luck.... I will appreciate anyone that can help me out... it will save me months and months of work thanks MUCH APPRECIATED !!!

```
My code:
import re
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def n(f):
    s = []
    for l in range(1):
        l = f.readline()
        if l:
            s.append(l)
    return s
b = open("lol.txt",'r', encoding='utf8')
c = n(b)
while len(c) > 0:
    for l in c:
        s = re.findall(r'\((.*?) *\)',l)
        print(s, sep='\n')
    c = n(b)
b.close()
```

```
Input:
(1,'4556','Книга включает в себя теорию действительных чисел, теорию пределов, теорию непрерывности функций, дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления функций одной переменной и их приложения, дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных и теорию неявных функций','','2011-01-29 09:31:10'),(2,'4557','Учебник представляет собой вторую часть (ч.1 - 1985) курса математического анализа. В книге рассмотрены теория числовых и функциональных рядов, теория кратных, криволинейных и поверхностных интегралов, теория поля (включая дифференциальные формы), теория интегралов, зависящих от параметра, и теория рядов и интегралов Фурье. Особенность книги - три четко отделяемых друг от друга уровня изложения: облегченный, основной и повышенный, что позволяет использовать ее как студентам технических ВУЗов с углубленным изучением математического анализа, так и студентам механико-математических факультетов университетов.','','2013-08-18 20:38:22')
```

```
# I want this type of Output
Output:
(1,'4556','Книга включает в себя теорию действительных чисел, теорию пределов, теорию непрерывности функций, дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления функций одной переменной и их приложения, дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных и теорию неявных функций','','2011-01-29 09:31:10')
(2,'4557','Учебник представляет собой вторую часть (ч.1 - 1985) курса математического анализа. В книге рассмотрены теория числовых и функциональных рядов, теория кратных, криволинейных и поверхностных интегралов, теория поля (включая дифференциальные формы), теория интегралов, зависящих от параметра, и теория рядов и интегралов Фурье. Особенность книги - три четко отделяемых друг от друга уровня изложения: облегченный, основной и повышенный, что позволяет использовать ее как студентам технических ВУЗов с углубленным изучением математического анализа, так и студентам механико-математических факультетов университетов.','','2013-08-18 20:38:22')
```

Comment: Is the question about printing 1 tuple per line ? If it is the case you should have shorten your example to focus on that ? Or do you have an error message ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you want, but here's my try:

```py
with open('lol.txt', '+r') as f:
    data = [l for l in eval(f.read())]

print('Output:\n')
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Comment: @Tiki--due to the Russian characters doesn't your `open()` need to specify the encoding?  I get an error with it as-is (on Windows).

Comment: I could not tell you, in Ubuntu it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

*Option 1--Using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)*

```
import ast

with open('a.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for x in ast.literal_eval(f.read()):
        print(x)
```

*Option 2--Using Regex*

```
import re

with open('a.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for x in re.findall(r"\(\d+,\'.*?\'\)", line):
            print(x)
```

**Output (both options)**

```
(1,'4556','Книга включает в себя теорию действительных чисел, теорию пределов, теорию непрерывности функций, дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления функций одной переменной и их приложения, дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных и теорию неявных функций','','2011-01-29 09:31:10')
(2,'4557','Учебник представляет собой вторую часть (ч.1 - 1985) курса математического анализа. В книге рассмотрены теория числовых и функциональных рядов, теория кратных, криволинейных и поверхностных интегралов, теория поля (включая дифференциальные формы), теория интегралов, зависящих от параметра, и теория рядов и интегралов Фурье. Особенность книги - три четко отделяемых друг от друга уровня изложения: облегченный, основной и повышенный, что позволяет использовать ее как студентам технических ВУЗов с углубленным изучением математического анализа, так и студентам механико-математических факультетов университетов.','','2013-08-18 20:38:22')
```

**Regex Explanation**

Regex pattern: **r"(\d+,'.*?')"**

```
\(                        - start with left paren 
\d+                      - one or more digits 
,                        - comma 
\'                       - single quote 
.*?                      - lazy wildcard character match
\'                       - single quote 
\)                       - closing paren
```

Comment: DarrylG thank you very much, your code fixed everything... I don`t know who put you on -1... You suppose to be +1000 thank you :) .....

Comment: @Leoley--glad to help.  I added a second option so now two: 1) AST, 2) Regex.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write just 3 lines of code.

```
with open("lol.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in eval(f.read()):
        print(line)
```

Input:

```
Input:
(1,'4556','Книга включает в себя теорию действительных чисел, теорию пределов, теорию непрерывности функций, дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления функций одной переменной и их приложения, дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных и теорию неявных функций','','2011-01-29 09:31:10'),(2,'4557','Учебник представляет собой вторую часть (ч.1 - 1985) курса математического анализа. В книге рассмотрены теория числовых и функциональных рядов, теория кратных, криволинейных и поверхностных интегралов, теория поля (включая дифференциальные формы), теория интегралов, зависящих от параметра, и теория рядов и интегралов Фурье. Особенность книги - три четко отделяемых друг от друга уровня изложения: облегченный, основной и повышенный, что позволяет использовать ее как студентам технических ВУЗов с углубленным изучением математического анализа, так и студентам механико-математических факультетов университетов.','','2013-08-18 20:38:22')
```

Output:

```
(1,'4556','Книга включает в себя теорию действительных чисел, теорию пределов, теорию непрерывности функций, дифференциальное и интегральное исчисления функций одной переменной и их приложения, дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных и теорию неявных функций','','2011-01-29 09:31:10')
(2,'4557','Учебник представляет собой вторую часть (ч.1 - 1985) курса математического анализа. В книге рассмотрены теория числовых и функциональных рядов, теория кратных, криволинейных и поверхностных интегралов, теория поля (включая дифференциальные формы), теория интегралов, зависящих от параметра, и теория рядов и интегралов Фурье. Особенность книги - три четко отделяемых друг от друга уровня изложения: облегченный, основной и повышенный, что позволяет использовать ее как студентам технических ВУЗов с углубленным изучением математического анализа, так и студентам механико-математических факультетов университетов.','','2013-08-18 20:38:22')
```